# how to animation right tick mark

Tags: android, animation

[image]

How to animate this symbol in a way we give right(correct).Please suggest me any code or library to implement this.

Answer (score 4):

You would need an [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html) - also available for API below 21 trough the support libraries.

For creating such animations, I just recently discovered the [AndroidIconAnimator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidIconAnimator/) which provides you with a nice timeline and preview of the result.

[image]

On top of that (for more complex animations) you can use [Vectalign](https://github.com/bonnyfone/vectalign) to calculate SVG paths for morphing:

[image]